# Cloudformation, cannot create resource of type `AWS::MSK::Configuration`

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create a `AWS::MSK::Configuration` resource, as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-msk-configuration.html.

This is my CF template:

```yaml
Resources:
  MSKConfig:
    Type: AWS::MSK::Configuration
    Properties:
      Description: Basic configuration.
      Name: test-msk-configuration
      ServerProperties: |
        auto.create.topics.enable=false
        ........
```

It doesn't work failing with the following error:

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Template format error: #Unrecognized resource types: [AWS::MSK::Configuration]
```

I'm not able to find any example with this resource type online. Has anyone ever used it?

Comment: Weird; have you tried a different region?

Comment: AWS documentation can be incorrect. Wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: Different region doesn't help

Answer (score 2):

Update on 26/03/2022:

I was able to get this deployed. I use the serverless framework for deployment.

MSK-Cluster.yml:

```
Resources:
  ServerlessMSK:
    Type: AWS::MSK::Cluster
    Properties:
      ClusterName: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-msk
      KafkaVersion: 2.6.2
      BrokerNodeGroupInfo:
        InstanceType: kafka.t3.small
        ClientSubnets:
          - !Ref ServerlessPrivateSubnet1
          - !Ref ServerlessPrivateSubnet2
          - !Ref ServerlessPrivateSubnet3
        SecurityGroups:
          - !GetAtt ServerlessMSKSecurityGroup.GroupId
        StorageInfo:
          EBSStorageInfo:
            VolumeSize: 10
      NumberOfBrokerNodes: 3
      EncryptionInfo:
        EncryptionInTransit:
          ClientBroker: TLS
          InCluster: true
      EnhancedMonitoring: PER_TOPIC_PER_BROKER
      ConfigurationInfo:
        Arn: !GetAtt ServerlessMSKConfiguration.Arn
        Revision: 1
```

MSK-config.yml

```
Resources:
  ServerlessMSKConfiguration:
    Type: AWS::MSK::Configuration
    Properties:
      Description: cluster for msk cluster-${sls:stage}
      Name: node-mongo-kafka-experiment-${sls:stage}-config
      ServerProperties: ${file('./assets/server.properties')}
```

server.properties

```
auto.create.topics.enable=true
default.replication.factor=2
min.insync.replicas=2
num.io.threads=8
num.network.threads=5
num.partitions=10
num.replica.fetchers=2
replica.lag.time.max.ms=30000
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
unclean.leader.election.enable=true
zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=18000
```

basically, no base64 was used. I just referenced the file in the deployment and managed to get it up. Hope this helps.

Orginal Answer Below:

I haven't been able to deploy this correctly too. But maybe I can point you in the right direction.I always get back a 400 error with my serverless deployment for this. The only thing I would like to add on here is that `serverproperties` must be a **Base64** encoded string.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-msk-configuration.html

My Template (that results in error):

```
Resources:
  ServerlessMSKConfiguration:
    Type: AWS::MSK::Configuration
    Properties:
      ServerProperties: !Base64 |
        auto.create.topics.enable=true
```

NB: Answering due to the fact I don't have reputation to comment.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the 400 issue, it looks like the `AWS::MSK::Configuration` resource suspects a `name`. While the documentation says it is not required.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-msk-configuration.html#cfn-msk-configuration-name

My template:

```
  KafkaConfiguration:
    Type: AWS::MSK::Configuration
    Properties:
      Name: Kafkaconfiguration
      ServerProperties: |
        auto.create.topics.enable=false
```

Comment: I have a name in my cloud formation template and yet it still fails.